# Alphanumerics with UCC128 barcode

Tags: barcode, alphanumeric, zpl, gs1-128

I have the following ZPL code

`^FO25,215^A0,N,25,25^BCN,100,N,N,N,U^FN21^FS`

The customer wants this barcode as a *UCC 128 barcode*, but their data is **alphanumeric**.

#### Research

I looked through the ZPL docs which mentions:

- option `U` for the mode defaults to *Subset C* which automatically strips out the alpha characters.
- can prepend the entry with `>9` or `>7` to make this *Subset A* which allows alphanumerics.

#### Issue

I tried:

`^FO25,215^A0,N,25,25^BCN,100,N,N,N,U^FN>721^FS`

But it still **removes the letters** from the barcode.
Not only that, but it adds `7` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that precludes using alphanumeric with UCC-128 (aka GS1-128).

#### GS1-128 compliant format

What you *must* do for a code128 barcode to be GS1-128 compliant is to format the data correctly.

That means the barcode data must be formatted as:

`<fnc1> <app-id> <value>`

Where:

1. `<FNC1>` character in ZPL is `>8` for all character sets.
2. `<app-id>` is the *application-identifier* (AI) for your barcode purpose
3. `<value>` is the (alpha-numeric) data to be encoded with the barcode

A good summary of UCC *application-identifiers* (AI) gives [UCC-128, EAN-128 & GS1-128 Bar Code Explained](https://web.archive.org/web/20170703124121/www.adams1.com/ucc128.html) (wayback archive from 2017).

#### Example

Let's say you would use an AI of `10` and are encoding the *batch number* `1702ABCD`.

Then  the resulting ZPL field data would be: `^FD>8101702ABCD^FS`

Comment: Glad it helped.  Could you please accept the answer.  Thx!